# Is 'and' ever not a conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions

Certain dictionary definitions of '[and](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/and/)' in lower-case letters are as a conjunction. In capital letters 'AND' is a noun as a Boolean operator. Below is an example of a request to a sign creator for a sign of symbols for Fish & Chips.

> Please give me symbols for: fish, 'fish' and and, '&' and chips, 'chips'.

In that example the word 'and' can be said to appear four times in a row. That first use of 'and' in the example sentence was as a conjunction why was it not a conjunction for the other three uses of the word 'and'? [Other users commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566213/can-you-say-more-than-four-and-words-in-a-row) about 'and' as something other than a conjunction. What is 'and' other than a conjunction?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124006/discussion-on-question-by-anil-london-is-and-ever-not-a-conjunction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* lists "and" as conjunction, adverb, and noun.

The adverb is labeled "obsolete".

> Ye shall see and what somewhat I have in my sacke.

The noun could be an instance of the word "and"

> ifs, ands or buts

Also the noun "and" may mean the boolean operation AND.

Comment: I was going to comment.  However, I'm thinking I should but out.

Comment: In the sense of boolean operation it can also be used as a verb: in computer science you might talk about how you need to "*and* two variables together", although this is very specialised and technical.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is not a conjunction when  it becomes a noun (or other) in usage or function.

Normally...

***And***

[is a conjunction](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/and), except for when it is being quoted as a word.

[-Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/and)

As [@Mitch](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/4972/mitch) mentions in a comment,

> See [Use-mention distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction). In short, 'and' is a conjunction, but " 'and' " is word that means a conjunction, which may seem like caviling but is an extremely important distinction. You can put a log into a wood chipper, but you can't put the word 'log' into a word chipper.

[Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth) said:

> "The 'word-used-as-a-word' is usually classed as a noun

---

Edit

I have been thinking on Mitch's comments.

I have heard "and" used as a demand for information: possibly it could function as an ***interjection***.

Ex.

> "Did you pick up your sister at the bus station?"
> "I went there..."
> ***"And??"***
> She wasn't there."

---

Final Notes:

Some folks here have noted in the past that although dictionaries list Parts of Speech, they   don't do a particularly good job of it.

Related: [What is the difference between a part of speech and a syntactic function / grammatical relation?.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217760/what-is-the-difference-between-a-part-of-speech-and-a-syntactic-function-gramm)

Comment: I don't usually reply formally to un-researched questions to which I have already VTCed...

Comment: The reason answers were confined to _comments_ is to avoid giving a veneer of respectability to an under-researched, badly stated and probably when undeciphered duplicate question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Should I delete? I was getting really tired of being pinged when I thought our comments should suffice. This guy is _just not getting it_...

Comment: I'd delete when OP has had chance to read this. They should read the other threads, and post problems they have remaining on ELL.

Comment: Although I'd agree this question isn't useful, I'm perplexed that the original question has been closed as a duplicate of what seems to me to be an entirely different question. Although the use-mention distinction is very relevant to the question about multiple "and"s in a row, the questions are by no means the same thing!

Comment: @tea-and-cake The question has not been closed  as a dupe; however,  it is still on the VTC queue for "lack of research"...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be a noun, like if I were to say:

> "And can be a noun— no ifs, ands, or buts!"

"No ifs, ands, or buts" is a common expression.  With that in mind, it's obvious the word "and" can be a noun because the word "and" has been pluralized. Conjunctions don't have a plural case. Nouns do. "And" being the subject of "can" above — so doubly proving its nounness — is the icing on the cake.

Incidentally, any [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/and) will tell you it can be a noun. Scrabble dictionaries even do since pluralizing "and" by adding an S in order to build in a perpendicular direction and get the points for "ands" in addition to the new word being formed is a strategic move.